# How do i make my image move across the page even when the resolution of screen changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image which goes from one side off the screen to other. However, when I open the HTML on a different sized computer/laptop, it does not fit and looks out of place. How do I fix this?

**CODE:**

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div.container {
  text-align: left;
  width: 710px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 12px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
div.content {
  width: 700px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mini {
  from {
    left: 410px;
  }
}
.mini {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 950px;
  width: 166px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 10000;
  -webkit-animation: mini 3s;
  animation: mini 8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="Media/buscartoon.jpg" class="mini" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly what the issue is. Do you have some illustration to aid?

Comment: Are you wanting to take the image to the right of the container and then back again or wanting to have the image transit to the right and stay there within the container?

Comment: @NasirT i want it to go from the left off the content to the right hand side off the content essentially

Comment: Ok. Can you explain the purpose of the top. Do you want it to go to the right straight or in an arc. You must clear what your end result should be like. This purpose is missing in your question so that is why trying to clear it.

Comment: Sorry i forgot i had that there, essentially the top at 0% sets the image to be at a certain position in the content. I updated the question @NasirT

Comment: @NasirT going to update my question i realize now it doesnt make sense

Comment: Ok. I have added in a answer but i now see you changed the css code in your question. Let me work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .content and .container have no position set, so I guess it's defaulting to the next parent element that does have these set.

Pop this on your .content div:

```
position: relative;
```

the image is still going to go over the limits because of left: 100% but adding a relative position to the container may well help you get to the next problem.

If you want the image to sit flush with the edge of the container rather than running over, you can also change your left: 100% to:

```
left: calc(100% - 100px)
```

...where 100px is the width of the element.

edit: jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/w56r2xnr/

Answer (score 1):

maybe set initial left and top values

```
 .imganim {
        width:100px;
        height:60px;
        position:absolute;
        -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s;
        animation:myfirst 5s;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css classes that i have ammended. I have kept the top at 5px which makes room for the 5px padding within the content div. Also the 50% transformation formal includes the left 100% - (width of the image + right-padding).

You can now adjust the top to make it as you see fit.

**CSS changes:**

```
 div.content {
    width: 700px; min-height: 400px;
    background-color: white; padding: 5px; 
    position: relative;
 }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst
    {
       0%   {left:0%; top:5px;}
        50%  {left: calc(100% - 105px);}
        100% {left:0%; top:5px;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes myfirst
    {
         0%   { left:0%; top:5px;}
        50%  {left: calc(100% - 105px);}
        100% {left:0%; top:5px;}
    }
```

Sample: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/ZBpjpw
Hope this helps.

**[Edit - Code changed in question]**

I think in both scenarios you will need to set the content div with `position:relative` to keep the image contained within it as the image itself is `position:absolute`. Along with that you need to use percentage values for the left and top in order for the animation and the position to be in the right place regardless of the size of the screen.

For the updated code in question please check the following code sample:

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/ObRwmO

Just adjust the key frame left percentage according to your need.

Comment: Sorry got pulled into back to back meetings. Yes i have updated the answer please check the new sample added after the [Edit] portion.

Comment: This doesnt work on my screen for some reason :/ it should goes along the way off the page

Comment: Sorry i dont understand can you share screenshot please.

Comment: @DrComputerScience: Please explain your problem better. Your are not making any sense. Read your problem statement. It has the code but does not elaborate " it does not fit and looks out of place" as we dont know what is out of place where it is out of place. Please share more info or screenshots to elaborate the problem. I have given both fixed examples of code you kept changing in your question to keep the img within the container and not go out of the container or reposition based on size. If you are looking for a responsive solution then i suggest you learn about responsive css first.